# Guice: inject dependency into @provides provider

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a module in which I create a provider and that provider is needed as a dependency for another provider in the same module. However, this is not currently possible with my setup. How can I solve this issue? It should also be noted that all the dependencies are third party libraries and so I believe that I should not be binding this in my module (according to what Ive read).

Unfortunately, due to NDA I cannot provide the actual code, but an example of the dependency hierarchy can be seen below:

```
public MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {}

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Engine provideEngine(){
        Map<String, String> engineProperties = new HashMap<>();
        engineProperties.put("brand", "some brand");
        engineProperties.put("capacity", "2.6 litres");
        return new Engine(engineProperties);
    }

    @Inject
    @Provides
    public Car provideCar(Engine engine){
        Car car = new Car(engine);
        return car;
    }
}
```

Is short, I need to create a custom Engine, setting up some properties before hand and then use that Engine as a dependency for the Car creation (please note that i am fully aware that I cannot inject using the @Inject annotation in the module, however, I put this simply as a reference to what I want to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the @Inject annotation and you should be good to go. As listed in [the @Provides Method User's Guide page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods):

> If the `@Provides` method has a binding annotation like `@PayPal` or `@Named("Checkout")`, Guice binds the annotated type. Dependencies can be passed in as parameters to the method. The injector will exercise the bindings for each of these before invoking the method.

Comment: I removed the @Inject, and tried to sys out the dependent object, i.e., the engine within the car provider, and Im getting null returned. Seems as though Im missing something here.

Comment: It'll be hard to move past here without seeing your code, or (for NDA's sake) a SSCCE that shows the same problem in runnable code. To be clear, though, you *are* letting Guice call these methods and not manually calling any `@Provides`-annotated methods, right?

Comment: Yes, Im letting Guice call these methods. Ill update the with running code, please bare with me a little while.

Comment: I created a simple project and yes its all wired up. I think that using my 3rd party libs is causing the error, not the way Im binding dependencies.